# Asp.net passing variables from Body to iframe

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, iframe

So I have created a small asp.net webpage that has a textbox and a button and I also added an iframe for a webpage that has a "label1" Title,
I would like the user to enter a word in the textbox and once the button clicked the Lable1.text will change.. so basically I want to pass the data from the parent textbox to the iframe label, can someone please guide me,
I am using Asp.net
Much appreciation

Comment: Can you share you markup with us

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please read the [ask] section in the help, and this [excellent article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just telling you the general concept and not asp.net specific.

You can assign an id to the iframe, and then you can access that iframe's document from the parent page as below -

```
//fraChild is the ID of the iframe
var objIframe = document.getElementById("fraChild"); 

//for sake of simplicity, lblTitle is a div created in the iframe 
//and that can be accessed as shown below
objIframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("lblTitle").innerHTML = "blah blah ..."
```

I hope this will help in getting the idea.

Comment: I'm sorry for not including my code, so the main asp page has a text box and a button  and an iframe,  when I click on the button, the iframe will become visible and will show the css page I have.  protected void preview_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iframe.Visible= true;
        }

Comment: protected void preview_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iframe.Visible= true;
            // here i want something that does this iframe.label1 = textbox1.Text; 
            // so the label1 is in iframe and the textbox1 is in the main page..
        }

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: i am happy to have helped you. Please take care to mark it as accepted answer if this solved your problem.